# Why are my spring-configuration-metadata.json properties not generated?

Tags: spring-boot

I've been able to generate a spring-configuration-metadata.json file with a proper groups section but my properties list is empty:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "test-configs",
      "type": "com.example.configpropsdemo.TestConfigs",
      "sourceType": "com.example.configpropsdemo.TestConfigs"
    }
  ],
  "properties": [],
  "hints": []
}
```

My configuration properties class looks like this:

```
@Validated
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test-configs")
public class TestConfigs extends ArrayList<TestConfigs.TestConfig> {

    @Validated
    public static class TestConfig {

        @NotBlank
        private String configName;

        @NotBlank
        private String username;

        @NotBlank
        private String password;

        //getters and setters...

    }
}
```

I'm using gradle and my build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

What gives?  Is there something I need to add to my TestConfigs class?

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `@Setter`.
Here is a simple example (STS4 - SpringBoot - Maven - RestTemplate - Microservices):

Client Class

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "brewery", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@Setter
public class BreweryClient {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String apihost;
    public final String BEER_PATH_V1 = "/api/v1/beer/";

    public BreweryClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
    
    public BeerDto getBeerById(UUID id) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(apihost + BEER_PATH_V1 + id.toString(), BeerDto.class);
    }
}
```

Test Class

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Slf4j
public class BreweryClientTest {

    @Autowired
    BreweryClient client;
    
    @Test
    public void testGetBeerById() {
        BeerDto beer = client.getBeerById(UUID.randomUUID());
        assertNotNull(beer);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
brewery.apihost=http://localhost:8080
```

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In my tests, you gotta use both `@Setter` and `@Getter` annotations. And if you're not into Lombok, you can just use pure setter and getter methods.